# Hibernate Row was updated or deleted by another transaction

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I'm getting `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):` in my java multi threading project.

I was trying to access same database record within two different threads. How can I fix this issue. This is the method I'm having error,

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Gamedetail getByExternalGameIdAndSource(String id, String dataSource) {
    return (Gamedetail) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Gamedetail.class).add(Restrictions.eq("externalgameid", id))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("datasource", dataSource)).uniqueResult();
}
```

I know the hibernate session is not support for multi threading. And I used the native sql query but then it gives me the class cast exception.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are some or one thread updates the same record? Because you should not get `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException ` while reading the records.

Comment: even if you could fix it , still,  the database wont allow you , to modify the same record / row at the same time

Comment: @Bunti Two threads are running same time and those two have infinite loops. So one loop is creating gameDetail objects. If you didnt found the particular gameDetail this method will return null then it create a new gameDetail record and save it otherwise update it. Other thread trying to access the gameDetail  and try to update some fields.

Comment: Does second thread also create `gameDetail` objects in addition to updating those records created by thread one?

Comment: @Bunti No its checking the record if its exist its updating otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Since both threads are updating records, you can catch `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` and update the record by fetching it back from DB. This option is suitable if you're so sure that updates to same record happen with a sufficiently large interval. But still this may open the possibility that either of the threads trying to update the same record and constantly failing with `StaleObjectStateException` exception. This may be rare, but can happen.

Comment: @Neero Can you post the full exception stack trace. Is there any code that is trying to update the rows. If so posting that along with GameDetail entity would help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I would opt for a solution where you'll have a shared queue which both threads will share and one thread will save/update `gameDetail` objects to database. That single thread will handle the cases where updates to non-existing records will simply create one in DB. You can either synchronise access to this queue or better you can also have thread safe concurrent queue such as [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Do remember that this approach may not yield better performance as there is a contention between two threads to get access to shared queue.